# Searching for something like submit complete event to turn loader off

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to use loader on my asp.net webforms app.
My javascript loader:

```
        function loading() {
            $("#loading").show();
        }

        function loaded() {
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
```

html loader

```
    <div id="loading">
         <span id="MessageLoader">Loading...</span>
         <img id="imgLoading" src="../Skin/images/blue-ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
```

It isn't the problem, it works fine every time I tried, my problem is how can I use this loader for every request?
I tried to use it by two ways:
First putting the loader call in every link, and uncall it when I load every page body onload event, it works fine, but when I hit links that open new tabs, new windows or download some file my loader never finish, see the code below:

```
        $('a').click(function () {
              if ($(this).attr('href') != '#'){
                 loading();
              }
        }
```

Second I used one resource that my pages have: every page on my system have inheritance with another in codebehind, so in parent page load I put this code below:

```
        ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", "loading();");
```

it works better than last one and it still with page body onload event to turn the loader off, but still with one problem, when I submit trying to download a file it don't do postback on page, so it don't put my loader down.
So, what can I do to do that? I searched for something like submit complete event but no sucess. My ideia is put the submit complete event on parent page, but I need to know the event. If you want to give me another ideias I will be grateful.

Comment: while opening a new tab/window, your current page becomes those in new tab/window. What you have to do with loader on the previous page? secondly how your main document can now the new page has loaded or not?

Answer (score 0):

while opening a new tab/window, your current page becomes those in new tab/window. What you have to do with loader on the previous page? secondly how your main document can now the new page has loaded or not?

Note: The `click` event is triggered immediately, and has a duration of 0, thus it doesn't have any callback.

But still if you need to load an gif for a while and hide after some time you setTimeout function.

[click for jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hfuGx/52/)

```
$('a').click(function () {
              if ($(this).attr('href') != '#'){
                  loading();
                  setTimeout(loaded, 3000); //3 secs
              }

});
```

Comment: All my pages are inside one page (it's not a master page) and their are used inside frame.
When my page do postback I have the loaded function inside my body onload event, so it is trusty. If I put setTimeout it won't be trusty, but I need this timeout if I know how to verify if the browser is busy or not